# how to retrieve the value from a dynamically created textbox using its ID in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

this is how i have added the dynamic textboxes in cells in a table in the form.

and i want to retrieve the values from the textboxes using its id and store it in a string

to generate a sql query

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To nov

        Dim tb As New TextBox()
        Dim tb2 As New DropDownList
        Dim tb3 As New TextBox()

        Dim tr As New TableRow()
        Dim tc As New TableCell()
        Dim tc2 As New TableCell()
        Dim tc3 As New TableCell()
        tb.ID = "txtName" + i.ToString()

        tb3.ID = "vv" + i.ToString()

        tb2.ID = "dd" + i.ToString()

        tb2.Items.Add("Int")
        tb2.Items.Add("Varchar")
        tb2.Items.Add("String")
        tblMain.Rows.Add(tr)
        tr.Cells.Add(tc)
        tc.Controls.Add(tb)


        tc2.Controls.Add(tb2)

        tr.Cells.Add(tc2)
        tc3.Controls.Add(tb3)
        tr.Cells.Add(tc3)

    Next
    Button2.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dim str As String=DirectCast(Page.FindControl("txtName"+i), TextBox).Text

it will not be accessable outside your loop, you will have to manage that with your code.

Comment: i am getting a runtime error like this
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: on which line? same line?

Comment: are u accessing its value in same method?

Comment: yes i am using a label to display the string just for testing purposes
eventually the final string will be implemented as an sql command

Comment: I am sorry, i cant debug your code at the moment as I am busy with office work, if possible I will give you solution after my work. Ectremely sorry.. one suggestion "try to use DirectCast in place of CType"

Comment: Dim str As String=DirectCast(Page.FindControl("txtName"+i), TextBox).Text

Comment: problem solved...i saved the value of nov using viewstate during postback :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Page.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

*"Searches the page naming container for a server control with the specified identifier."*

e.g.

```
Dim t As TextBox= CType(Page.FindControl("txtName1"), TextBox)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TextControl()
        Dim txt As New TextBox
        txt.Text = ""
        txt.Name = "txt" & Val(no)
        txt.Size = New Size(44, 22)
        txt.Text = m
        txt.Location = New Point(tx, ty)

        GroupBox2.Controls.Add(txt)
        ty = ty + incr
        no = Val(no) + 1
    End Sub

Dim textBoxValue As String = CType(GroupBox2.Controls(txt.Name), TextBox).Text.Trim
```